# Is compiler directive WIN32 and CPUX86, WIN64 and CPUX64 interchangeable in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, compiler-directives

Is  compiler directive WIN32 and CPUX86,  WIN64 and CPUX64 interchangeable in Delphi?

If yes, Which one is preferred?
If no, why?

Comment: The documentation can tell you the answer: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whether or not they are interchangeable depends on platforms you are developing for.

Generally, if you are doing only Windows development then they are interchangeable, otherwise not.

`WIN32` is defined only for Windows 32bit platform, and `WIN64` is defined only for Windows 64bit platform.

However, `CPUX86` is defined for several platforms: Windows 32bit, OSX 32bit, and iOS 32bit simulator.

Right now `WIN64` and `CPUX64` are only defined for Windows 64bit platform, so at the moment they are interchangeable, but that may change in the future.

Which directive you should use depends on your code. Use directive that conveys proper meaning. If part of code is meant only to run on Windows 32bit platform then use `WIN32` directive, if it is meant to run on any platform but under 32bit x86 processor then you should use `CPUX86`.

[Predefined Conditionals](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi))

Comment: Nice and clear answer. Actually I don't know why I am asking this simple question, I should have figured out by myself.

Comment: Great you mention the reference *Predefined Conditionals* - maybe even better if it was in a concluding sentence.